# Creating namespaces by creating folders and nested the folders or Creating folders name with dots?

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

The question might sound weird but it just came into my mind while I was creating a new project.

In Visual Studio, I can create a namespaces hierarchy as below as nested folders or I could just create individual folders with dot such as CompanyName.Common and CompanyName.Common.Util

Which one makes more sense in long run and for big projects? or would it make any better than the other?

Second question is is there any limitation in terms of how deep it can go or is there any performance affect of having 7-8 nested namespaces?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your namespace names and your project folder structure are two separate things.

They just seem related because Visual Studio creates a default namespace name for you, each time you create a new folder and start creating classes inside it, based on the name of the folder and what other folders it's nested inside of.

However, you can rename those namespaces to anything you want. For example, the first class you create in "CompanyName.Common" will be given the namespace "TestPro.CompanyName.Common", but you can rename that to "MyNewNameSpace" if you want.

> Which one makes more sense in long run and for big projects? or would it make any better than the other?

In the end, your folder structure is just a matter of whatever makes the most sense to you, and helps you keep things organized. If you like seeing everything at once, flattened out, then use the folders with dots in them. Personally, I prefer nesting folders, but it's really up to you.

> Is there any limitation in terms of how deep it can go or is there any performance affect of having 7-8 nested namespaces?

Personally, I haven't had a reason to nest more than 3 or 4 folders deep. Either way you choose, you're more likely to hit a [windows limitation of 260 characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) before running into problems in Visual Studio performance (unless you're naming your folders with single letters or something unusual):

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters.

Indeed, it's not that hard to hit (my folder names are ridiculous here, but I'm making a point ;) )

[image]

Comment: Yes I am aware of that you can rename the namespaces what you like but it doesnt make sense to do that. things get complicated in the future. I also use resharper and it complains if the class has different namespaces than folder structure. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have just updated the question with something related the level of namespaces.. would you mind answering that question? thanks

Comment: If you find anything please let me now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It turns out there's a Windows limitation of 260 characters for file paths, so I think you're more likely to hit that first. I didn't find anything documented about the maximum number of nested folders VS allows, or how that might negatively affect the performance of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, every industrial project I worked on had a clear nested folder hierarchy. It seems like Microsoft also recommends nested folders from the links I've quickly looked at.

Example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668954.aspx